# Cannot start DBDesigner

Tags: software-installation

I want to start DBDesigner app which I have already downloaded [from here](http://fabforce.net/downloadfile.php?iddownloadfile=2). And I did exactly what they say on this page:

> Download the file to your HOME directory. 
>   Extract the tar archive by executing
>   tar xvzf DBDesigner4.0.5.4.tar.gz from the command line. Change to the created directory (cd DBDesigner4) and run ./startdbd.sh to start DBDesigner 4.

But when I try to run `./startdbd.sh` it says

```
no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

My zsh screenshot:

[image: my zsh screenshot]

Comment: Do `./startdbd`, i.e., drop the `.sh` part.

Comment: @edwinksl, thanks, it worked. But now it just says:
`Symbolic links exist
Starting DBDesigner4 ...`
and then it shows command prompt. Nothing else happens

Comment: i've cheked log file and it says _libXft.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory_

Comment: Please try : `ls -l` to watch the timestamps = **year 2003** ! .... Next : Please do :  `file DBDesigner4` ... and be informed that DBDesigner4 is a 32bits application.